# Count clicks to each of two external sites in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, links, click-tracking

My client is a theatre company and they have lists of shows on their site. When the user clicks on a show, they get the option to book a ticket via site X or site Y.

They want to know how many people book via site X vs Y for each show in the list, but also how many book via site X vs Y for all shows together.

I'm happy to poke around in GA once I've got the data, but since the data takes a couple of days to come in, I wondered if someone could help me record it correctly in the first place...

Comment: With JavaScript you may use GA events to track how many people chose site X or Y. But if the booking happens in a different site, there's no way to know if they have completed the booking.

Comment: Thanks Osvaldo. I should have probably been more specific in my question: I'm just looking to track clicks on those links. I guess I'm asking what should I set eventCategory, eventAction and eventLabel to, so that I'll then be able to use the data as described above?

Comment: You're thinking is on the right track with the event parameters. Have you taken a look at this resource: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events?

Comment: Yes they can work as a hierarchy and you can also use event value.

Comment: Thanks all. I'd read a bit about the different fields, and was guessing I'd do something like eventCategory: "Booking link", eventAction: "Site X" and eventLabel: "Name of show". I just wanted to check that the GA control panel would then let me filter and sort that data as required. Since it's a clients site, would be nice to set it up once and make it work rather than do lots of trial and error!